# bitwise rotating whole text

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

For the fun of it, I am trying to bitwise rotate a whole text to right. Meaning, I want every character's last bit (lsb) end up being next character's first bit (msb) and last character's last bit to be first character's first bit. Here is what I have tried;

```
def bitwise_text_rotate(text):
    # make a list of ascii codes
    characters = [ord(a) for a in text]

    # save last character's right-most bit
    carry_bit = characters[-1] & 1

    # list of processed characters
    output = []

    for char in characters:
        print "processing", char
        last_bit = char & 1
        char = char >> 1
        mask = (carry_bit << 8) & 1
        char = char & mask
        print "appending", char
        output.append(char)
        carry_bit = last_bit

    return "".join([chr(a) for a in output])
```

But it doesn't work. I am getting all zeros. Any ideas how I could do this better, or what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you do that, it will no longer be valid ASCII.

Comment: @MarkByers It is ok. I am just curious about how to achieve this. Plus, if I can do this, I can do left-rotation too and have myself a little encryption algorithm :)

Comment: It's not really encryption: it's one-to-one, so anyone could reverse it without a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = map(ord, text)
return ''.join(chr(((a&1)<<7) + (b>>1)) for a,b in zip(s[-1:] + s, s))
```

Comment: Good one. It took me a while to get it though.

Answer (score 1):

These lines are incorrect:

```
mask = (carry_bit << 8) & 1
char = char & mask
```

Use:

```
mask = carry_bit << 7
char = char | mask
```

Comment: Changing that line alone didn't change the result. I am still getting all zeros.

Comment: Sorry, not in front of a comp...next line is wrong too.  Amended answer.

Comment: Ok, I also realized that I should have shifted 7, not 8. You could also add that into your answer to make it complete.